# Binary Search Off By 1 Infinite Loop

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

So I have the following binary search algorithm that sometimes runs into an infinite loop:

```py
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        i, j = 0, len(nums)-1
        mid = (j+i)//2
        while i<j: 
            if nums[mid] == target:
                return mid
            if nums[mid] > target: 
                j = mid
                mid = (j+i)//2
            else: 
                i = mid
                mid = (j+i)//2                
        
        return mid if nums[mid] == target else -1
```

The correct version has that `j = mid+1` and `i = mid-1`. In certain cases, the code above will run into an infinite loop if the mid pointer is not with in the interval bounded by i and j. Why does that happen, and more importantly, why does having the different assignments prevent that?

An example test case is:

```py
nums = [-1,0,3,5,9,12], target = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for making a binary search that doesn't produce an infinite loop is to make sure that every case always narrows the search space.  Since you've already checked `mid`, you can set your bounds so that it isn't included in the range any more.  You can also simplify your code to calculate `mid` at the top of the loop so you're not doing it redundantly for every case.

```
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        i, j = 0, len(nums)-1
        while i<j:
            mid = (j+i)//2
            if nums[mid] == target:
                return mid
            if nums[mid] > target: 
                j = mid - 1
            else: 
                i = mid + 1
        
        return i if nums[i] == target else -1
```

Comment: It seems that only assigning one of ```j``` or ```i``` to their respective updates also works for binary sort. Why is that?

Comment: @user2793618 I'm not sure what you're asking, can you rephrase it?

Comment: So instead of having both ```j = mid-1``` and ```i = mid+1```. It seems that binary sort will also work if we just have  ```j = mid-1``` and ```i=mid``` or  ```i = mid+1``` and ```j=mid```. Why is that?

Comment: @user2793618 but it doesn't work with `j=mid`, if you search for `0` in the list `[1,2,3]` you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.  A similar case will exist for `i=mid`.

Answer (score -1):

Using your sample test case, the 2nd iteration gives:

`i = 0`, `j = 2`, and `mid = 1`

then at the 3rd iteration, it gives:

`i = 1`, `j = 2`, and `mid = 1`

If you track it further, `mid = 1` will be the repeating result as i is always `1` and j is always `2`. This is the cause of the infinite loop.

Here is a refactored version that captures your provided edge case:

```
nums = [-1, 0, 3, 5, 9, 12]
target = 2


def search(nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    i, j = 0, len(nums)-1
    mid = (j+i)//2
    while i < j:
        print(i, j, mid)
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        if nums[mid] > target:
            j = mid
            mid = (j+i)//2
        elif nums[mid] < target and nums[mid+1] < target:
            i = mid
            mid = (j+i)//2
        else:
            return -1

    return mid if nums[mid] == target else -1
```

I would refactor it further to become more simple and readable:

```
def search(nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    i, j = 0, len(nums)-1
    while i < j:
        mid = (i+j)//2
        if nums[mid] < target:
            i = mid+1
        elif nums[mid] > target:
            j = mid-1
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
```

Explanation: if `nums[mid]>target`, we ignore right half and the vice versa. if our indexes have converged (i.e. i==j) and we still did not find the target, return -1

Comment: Do you have a intuitive explanation or proof for the correctness? That's more what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2793618 you are not disqualifying the current index (i or j) when selecting for new search range. In the normal implementation this is what i+1 and j-1 is for. In your implementation it does not exist.

Comment: Right, I want to know why that would make it work. I know that the current implementation won't work, but I want to know the mathematical reasoning behind it